# How to force real-time display updates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get javascript to update my webpage in real-time?
It seems that my Chrome browser puts all of its processing effort into required computations, and then does the webpage updates.  Below is the simplest test HTML file.  I would prefer to see sequential counting (instead of just one jump to the final value).  What should I replace `display.innerHTML = i;` with?

I hope the answer is not to break up my computation into many computations using setInterval or something like that.  Of course, the breaks this creates will allow display updates, but I prefer not to manage it in such detail...I am hoping that there is a "blocking" display function available, so that the count here will not proceed until the browser renders my display update (or is there is a "flush" command like C provides?).  I could use the developer console if needed, but that is also not ideal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="Display"></p>
<script>
const display  = document.getElementById("Display");
for (let i = 0; i <= 3000000000; i++) {
            if (i %   100000000 == 0) display.innerHTML = i; }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There isn't. You use setTimeout... or use a web worker.

Comment: @epascarello I'd like to see my code rewritten using setTimeout as an answer, it's not so easy.

Comment: use Promise to push the task to force wait

Comment: @mickey what about using `setTimeout` is not so easy?

Comment: Why is it important to count on such a large scale, 100M -> 3B? Perhaps some insight here would allow for a broader answer set.

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa I don't want to break up my counting computation here because the actual not-so-simple computation I will eventually use this for has recursive calls of functions to themselves.  I know easy is relative, so I won't argue this further.

Comment: @mickey I am not trying to argue anything. The reason I was asking is because simply claiming something 'isn't easy' doesn't help us with helping you through the issue. If you perhaps explain *why* it isn't easy or what issues you run into when you try, then we actually have something to address and we aren't shooting shots in the dark to try and help you out

Answer (score 2):

`requestAnimationFrame` way

Using requestAnimationFrame or setTimeout where you exit the loop to let it allow the UI to be updated and you resume the loop where you left off.

```js
const display = document.getElementById("Display");

function process() {

  let index = 0;
  const max = 3000000000;
  
  function run () { 
    while (index <= max) {
      if (index % 100000000 == 0) {
        display.innerHTML = index;
        break;
      }
      index++;
    }
    if (index++ <= max) window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
  }
  
  run();
}

process();
```

```html
<p id="Display"></p>
```

---

[**The web worker way**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Put your algorithm in a JS file where it posts a message when it wants an update

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 3000000000; i++) {
    if (i %   100000000 == 0) self.postMessage(i);
}
```

and in your UI code.

```js
const display  = document.getElementById("Display");
const myWorker = new Worker("workerAlgorithm.js");
myWorker.onmessage = (e) => {
  display.innerHTML = e.data;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still wish there was a simpler way to just block the counting, like a person who reads my original code/procedure would almost expect.  I'd say you've made a simple "count and display" procedure hard to understand here, but maybe this is the only way :(

Comment: @mickey - The complication here though, which isn't quite as simple as it seems, is that while your computer may count at 1M or 1B times per second, most browsers only refresh their display 60 times per second.

Comment: @TravisJ Same thing holds in C consoles, but I can flush their buffers.

Comment: So then go the web worker way where the update is in the code and the code that does the processing posts updates to it. You have to work with what you got. You can wish all you want, but it is not going to change how JavaScript currently works.

Comment: @mickey - I believe the C console is using the system refresh rate, which would be dependent on the actual display being used, 120 or 240 isn't all that uncommon in some setups nowadays. Most rendering in an html environment has an imposed limit at 60.

Answer (score 1):

As [@epascarello mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76682327/how-to-force-real-time-display-updates-in-javascript#comment135193993_76682327), using a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) is the conventional way to handle computational tasks off of the main thread — **in order to prevent blocking renders**. Below is a simple example that you can use to reproduce.

> It appears that Stack Overflow won't execute worker scripts from blob URLs in snippets, so you'll need to save the code as a local HTML file, serve it with a local http server, and navigate to it in your browser. Here's a link to a publicly hosted copy of the example: https://jsfiddle.net/zsb7cou5/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <title>Compute on a separate thread</title>

  <script type="module">
    const display = document.getElementById("Display");
    
    const workerScriptSource = `
    for (let i = 0; i <= 3_000_000_000; i += 1) {
      if (i % 100_000_000 === 0) self.postMessage(i);
    }
    self.close();
    `;

    const workerScriptUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([workerScriptSource], { type: "text/javascript" }),
    );
    
    const worker = new Worker(workerScriptUrl, { type: "module" });
    
    worker.addEventListener("message", (ev) => {
      display.textContent = ev.data;
    });
    
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="Display"></p>
</body>

</html>
```